# Calculating temperature of partial condenser, flash calculations

Tags: thermodynamics, chemical-engineering

The iterative method I have learned to make flash calculations for a binary system where I know the inlet feed (F [mol/s]), total composition of the two components ($z_1$ and $z_2$), the amount of the mixture which is evaporated (q) and the total pressure (P [mmHg]) is as follows:

1. We seek T, $x_i$ (composition of liquid) and $y_i$ (composition of gas). We know F, $z_i$, q, P.
2. Guess T
3. Calculate $P_1°$ and $P_2°$. In our course we are using Antoine's equation to do this. Antoine's equation can be written in many ways but lets for simplicity stick with this version. That is:
   $$P_i°(T)=10^{A_i-\frac{B_i}{C_i+T}}$$
   where T is in °C and P in mmHg. $A_i,B_i,C_i$ are the Antoine constants and they are known.
4. Calculate $x_i$ and $y_i$. For simplicity we say that $\gamma_i=1$. This gives us that:
   $$x_i=\frac{Fz_i}{V\frac{P_i°(T)}{P}+L}$$
   and
   $$y_i=\frac{P_i°(T)x_i}{P}$$
   where V is the gas outlet stream ($V=q\cdot F$) and L is the liquid outlet stream ($L=(1-q)\cdot F$).
5. If $\sum x_i=1$ $\underline{and}$ $\sum y_i=1$ you have found the correct T, $x_i$ and $y_i$. Else go back to 2.

So my question is. Do we really need to calculate $\underline{both}$ $y_i$ and $x_i$? If I find the temperature which satisfies $\sum x_i=1$ doesn't that guarantee that also $\sum y_i=1$? I plotted this and played around with different values for the Antoine constants and values for F, q and P. Here is a link to my plot: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/m37slkdebb. For all of my cases it was true that if for a temperature T $\sum x_i=1$ then also $\sum y_i=1$ for that same temperature T. I asked my professor about this and he insisted that I would have as a requirement to stop my iteration when $\sum x_i=1$ $\underline{and}$ $\sum y_i=1$.

Am I correct that $\sum x_i=1$ guarantees $\sum y_i=1$?

Are there cases I have missed where you can have several temperatures where $\sum x_i=1$ but only one of these temperaturs satisfies both $\sum x_i=1$ and $\sum y_i=1$?

What happens when $\gamma_i\neq1$, is this simplification too much? If i use another model for $P_i°$ what will happen then?

Comment: In my judgment your professor is correct.  The sum of the mole fractions of vapor is a constraint on this problem.  There is only one T and set of x's that satisfies this constraint.